# Bought a new xbox and trying to transfer files from another drive to it

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I had an original Xbox 360 but it broke so I got the slim. I had a 60gb hard drive on the original with GTA V, Skyrim DLCs and saves on it. I went and bought a hard drive transfer cable to transfer the saves to my new Xbox.

I want to keep playing Skyrim from where I left off. Do I have to install the DLC disc again or do I just insert the play disc? I already moved everything to the Xbox Slim. I went ahead and put in the play disc but all it said is:

> Loading downloadable content. Please wait..

It just does that and hasn't done anything. Do I have to wait an amount of time or do I have to insert the second disc again and then play?

Answer (score 3):

I have never had problems transferring saves, but have had problems when transferring games.  Specifically, my issue was with arcade games (i.e. games downloaded via the marketplace, which I then transferred through the cable to another console's hard dribe).

I needed to re-download these games in some cases because they wouldn't start.  I believe it is some hiccup in the licensing (because each game is associated with a console and/or gamertag).  Copying the game may have left the old console info as part of the game files, which may prevent you from playing on the new console.

It may be worth reinstalling the DLC disk before trying anything else.

If your DLC was from the marketplace (i.e. not on disc) you can use your download history to redownload.  Doing it this way will mean the download is a couple of seconds rather than waiting for the full download.  It will fix issues with licensing.

Don't forget to do a license transfer to your new console.  This will allow you to play any DLC or downloaded game (i.e non-disc game, such as arcade titles) offline.  Note, you will need to re-download each and every DLC/downloaded game after a license transfer to apply the changes.

More information **[here.](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-360/store/download-content)**